# Remove any object inserted in a LinkedList implemented as Queue

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, queue

I have a LinkedList implemented as Queue. The method remove(object) can remove the object anywhere in the Queue, which according to my knowledge contradicts with the concept of FIFO of Queue. What I'm i understanding wrong in this.

```
Queue<Object> q= new LinkedList<>();
//assuming objects have been inserted 
q.remove(a); //this removes the object 'a' present anywhere in the Queue.
```

Comment: Well, if you don't want to remove an element anywhere in the queue, don't call this method.

Comment: Okay, but is this method useful anywhere, I'm currently learning Java so wanted to know where would this be useful.

Comment: It's useful when you want to delete an object from a collection (whether it's a queue or any collection)

Comment: @JBNizet why would you want that on a Queue?

Comment: Haven't you ever been in the middle a queue for a restaurant or a movie, and finally decided to go elsewhere? That's one reason you might want that for a queue.

Comment: Supporting additional operations is not a contradiction of the queue concept. Otherwise, not even the `toString()` method was allowed.

Comment: But the [Queue#remove](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#remove()) method in Java doesn't accept any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, I looked into the remove method within LinkedList Object and Collection interface.
What remove function does is that it will iterate through the nodes, find the object, it will unlink the object.

> ```
>     public boolean remove(Object o) {
>     if (o == null) {
>         for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
>             if (x.item == null) {
>                 unlink(x);
>                 return true;
>             }
>         }
>     } else {
>         for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
>             if (o.equals(x.item)) {
>                 unlink(x);
>                 return true;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Now, the unlink method is basically functioning with a node, just as queue, iterating with left and right to find that object.
Also, keep in mind that this object has a modCount, which tracks the modification and implement fast-fail behavior (if something goes bogus)

> ```
> E unlink(Node<E> x) {
>     // assert x != null;
>     final E element = x.item;
>     final Node<E> next = x.next;
>     final Node<E> prev = x.prev;
>
>     if (prev == null) {
>         first = next;
>     } else {
>         prev.next = next;
>         x.prev = null;
>     }
>
>     if (next == null) {
>         last = prev;
>     } else {
>         next.prev = prev;
>         x.next = null;
>     }
>
>     x.item = null;
>     size--;
>     modCount++;
>     return element;
> }
> ```

Not a complete answer at all, however, you can see, it traverses through nodes. Maybe you could look into Big O and algorithms through books and tutorials. However, simply put, LinkedList is kind of mixed bag, implementing here and there.
So, FIFO will be kept, and the index will be kept tracked, *however*, will traverse to do remove other than cutting head or tail node.